# SQL SUM stop if hit a threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a back testing where I need to calculate each store's losses if I apply a $1000 threshold block on the sale_amount.

For example, store_id = a, the first two rows add up to 700, but the third transaction = $400 will still go through, total 700+ 400 =1100, then a batch process to run and trigger the 1000 block, so the 4rd trans get blocked, what I need to calculate is the all the amount after the block being triggered, which is store_id = a , which is $99.  store b is $800+100+50

This is my sample data, please advise how to use temporary table to solve this

```
Create table stadium 
(
     Trans_id int, 
     Store_id varchar, 
     sale_amount int
)

insert into stadium (Trans_id, Store_id, sale_amount) values ('1', 'a', '500')
insert into stadium (Trans_id, Store_id, sale_amount) values ('2', 'a', '200')
insert into stadium (Trans_id, Store_id, sale_amount) values ('3', 'a', '400')
insert into stadium (Trans_id, Store_id, sale_amount) values ('4', 'a', '99')
insert into stadium (Trans_id, Store_id, sale_amount) values ('5', 'b', '700')
insert into stadium (Trans_id, Store_id, sale_amount) values ('6', 'b', '100')
insert into stadium (Trans_id, Store_id, sale_amount) values ('7', 'b', '800')
insert into stadium (Trans_id, Store_id, sale_amount) values ('8', 'b', '100')
insert into stadium (Trans_id, Store_id, sale_amount) values ('9', 'b', '50')
```

Comment: Please update your question with your best attempt at resolving this issue yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this requires a recursive CTE -- because you hit a threshold, but skip and keep on going.

So, this does what you describe:

```
with s as (
      select s.*, row_number() over (partition by store_id order by trans_id) as seqnum
      from stadium s
     ),
     cte as (
      select store_id, trans_id, sale_amount as running_amount, 1 as include_flag, seqnum
      from s
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select s.store_id, s.trans_id,
             (case when s.sale_amount + cte.running_amount <= 1000 then s.sale_amount + cte.running_amount else cte.running_amount end),
             (case when s.sale_amount + cte.running_amount <= 1000 then 1 else 0 end),
             s.seqnum
      from cte join
           s
           on s.store_id = cte.store_id and s.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select s.*
from cte join
     s
     on s.trans_id = cte.trans_id
where include_flag = 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8115688d4074a0e1c7fb0243b3e70107) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: would you mind convert it into a way that use temp table, it's hard for me to understand

Comment: You can't use recursion without a CTE.